# Pan within large image borders with LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am building a small testing game, basically where is waldo. I have a large image that I can pan around and look for Waldo, but I can't figure out how to keep the camera within the sprite borders (x, y). Right now you can pan past the image borders and on and on and on forever.

Relevant code:

```
sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);

public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        camera.translate(-deltaX * PAN_SPEED, deltaY * PAN_SPEED);
        camera.update();
        return true;
    }
```

there isn't much, I've tried quite a few things but the problem is I can't figure out how to get the distance I have panned, and I need that if I am going to put up a "border". Right now the `sprite.getX() == -2200)`, and the camera viewport is only `(480x800)`, so I am having a hard time working with the Image size and the viewport, and the distance that has been panned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to solve this before, but I did it very inelegantly.  I basically just had a log printing out my current camera's position as I panned around.  When I could see off the edge of the screen (to the blank GL wipe underneath), I wrote down the camera's position.

I ended up knowing that if the camera.getX() > sprite.getWidth() - someVal, the edge would on screen.  So, I just added in a method that clipped down any X/Y val of a camera if it over shot these predefined bounds.

It's not a great answer, but it also allows you control.

Comment: At least you are trying to help. I think this can actually get me far enough to solve it so I will accept :)